# Set width in Bootstrap td

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, width, html-table

I have this table and I want to make the dots-button cell's width equal to the button width.
How can I make it possible?
And also I would make the entire cell with no border and no background color, but I don't know how I can. I think there's a Bootstrap class interfering.

[image]

```
<div class="col-md-12 column table-responsive" id="tablaPagos" style="padding-right:0;">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tabla_cobros_programados">
        <thead class="thead-gray">
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-2 text-center">
                    Fecha
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-3 text-center">
                    Concepto
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-3 text-center">
                    Monto
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-3 text-center">
                    Detalle
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p class="text-center">22/08/2016</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="text-center">Fotocopias<p></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="text-center">1800</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="text-center">1000 fotocopias</p>
                </td>
                <td class="pull-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To set the dots-button cell's width equal to the button width, remove class `pull-right` from the last `td`.
2. To make the entire cell with no border and no background color write in css:

   ```
    td{
     text-align:center;
     border:none!important;
     background:transparent;
     color:#fff;
    }

    table{
     background:transparent!important;
    }
   ```

If you want to remove borders from th cells too, just apply same css for that too.

Here is working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26494/).